# C# добавления программы в автозагрузку Windows10 64x

Tags: c#, реестр

Есть такой код :

```
public static bool SetAutorunValue(bool autorun)
{
    string executablePath = Application.ExecutablePath;
    var nameApp = "SimpleEditor";
    RegistryKey reg;
    reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
    if (autorun)
    {
        if (reg.GetValue(nameApp) == null)
        {
            reg.SetValue(nameApp, executablePath);
            reg.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (reg.GetValue(nameApp) != null)
        {
            reg.DeleteValue(nameApp);
            reg.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

1. Ошибок/исключений не выдает
2. В Диспетчере задач показывает что программа добавлена в автозагрузку, но "Открыть расположение  файла" в диспетчере задач тоже не работает.
3. При старте OC, программа не запускается.
4. Ключ в ветке  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run не создается.
5. Работаю из под админа

Comment: а программа запущена под админом? Обычно даже работая из-под админа программы запускаются с ограниченным доступом.

Comment: Система же 64-битная? Тогда либо приложение должно быть скомпилировано под x64 (не Any CPU), либо при обращении к реестру нужно явно указывать, что вам нужна 64-битная его версия. Изучите вопрос доступа к x64 реестру из x86 приложений. И для модификации ветки реестра CurrentUser вроде не нужны права админа.